# Determining power under the assumption that Z_0(test statistic) has the variance of 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, standardization

My apology if there already are similar questions.

On statistical hypothesis testing;
When you design the test for the estimate of binomially-distributed population's mean and are determining the power, is it possible to calculate the power under the assumption that the test statistic Z_0's variance is 1?

My textbook says that Z_0 is calculated assuming the null hypothesis H_0 is true and standardized to have the variance of 1, but does this '1 variance' hold true when assuming that the alternate hypothesis H_1 is correct?

Especially when the variance is unknown and calculated using the estimate of mean(like in the case of binomial distribution), it seems to me that Z_0's variance that is calculated assuming H_0 is no longer equal to 1 under H_1, and thus it is invalid to calculate the power using the likes of standard normal distribution table.

Comment: This looks too vague to answer.  Please tell us specifically what "Z_0" is.  I suspect, but am not sure, you might be confounding two different senses of "variance." The standardization is in terms of the *data,* not the probability model.  The model (whether $H_0$ or $H_A$) does not affect the standardization at all.